# How to hide a word from text through CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a website through WordPress and for some reason, I can edit the CSS but not the HTML code, and I want to hide some text but not all of it. The code is:

I want to hide "CATEGORY:"

```
<div class="page-heading">
  <div class="page-title">
     <h2>Category: Vegetables</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try negative text-indent and overflow:hidden

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you can't add a `span` tag to the HTML code and therefore cannot not seperate "Category: " from the rest of the text to address it using CSS, you could use Javascript/jQuery:

You can use the following script. It removes "Category: " from the text by replacing it with nothing and will be applied to *any*  `h2` within a `.page-title` element that is inside a `.page-heading` element.

```js
var myheader = $('.page-heading .page-title h2').text();
var changedtext = myheader.replace("Category: ", "");
$('.page-heading .page-title h2').text(changedtext);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-heading">
  <div class="page-title">
    <h2>Category: Vegetables</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so how come I first get a downvote for an answer that is later accepted as the correct answer plus a comment similar to this one which I wrote yesterday disappears?

Answer (score -1):

USed this cdn https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

https://codepen.io/stanley3569/pen/qBdwpQq

```
<h2>Category: Vegetables</h2>
```

css

```
.hiddenText {
  opacity: 0;  
}
```

js

```
$("h2").html(function(){
  var text= $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
  var first = text.shift();
  return (text.length > 0 ? "<span class='hiddenText'>"+ first + "</span> " : first) + text.join(" ");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
#cat_hide     {
display: none;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Note : You want hide any content  you must lock that 
content with any possible tag.  -->
 <div class="page-title">
<h2><span Id="cat_hide">Category:</span> 
  Vegetables</h2>
</div>
</body>
```